# Getting error while running blink example of CC3200 in Energia IDE

Tags: embedded

error: MSP430: Error initializing emulator: No USB FET was found
Failed: MSP430: Error initializing emulator: No USB FET was found

error: MSP430: Error initializing emulator: No USB FET was found

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: Tons of results on the web: google it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using code composer 7, where you can get the same error.
The message indicates that the tool is looking for an MSP430 board to connect to, allthough you have a CC3200 board connected.
In CCS you achieve it by opening the target window and importing the CC3200.ccxml file (right click it and set it as default).

In Energia, you'll have to set your target as well. By default CC3200 isn't provided, go to the board management:
[board management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fasx.jpg)
and scroll down.  There You'll find a topic CC3200 boards. Click it and an install button will appear:
[install cc3200 target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/257Lm.jpg)

After installation, the board should appear in the target list and you should be able to select it: